# How to check for a sub-string when the given string doesn't have any spaces (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, string, logic

Can someone help me to check whether the given sub-string exists or not in a sentence (string) which doesn't have spaces.

For example:

```
let subString = 'for';
let string = 'iamgoingforawalk'; //(I am going for a walk)
```

*Note: Please note that I am using Node js for implementation.*

Comment: use regex to find string exist or not. or 'iamgoingforawalk'.includes('for') // true

Comment: @RahulSharma please do not recommend people to use regex when its simply not needed. Stick to the KISS principle.

Comment: @KamilSolecki sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function includes.

```
string.includes(subString);
```

example:

```
console.log('howareyou'.includes('are')); //true
```

Comment: mention not@SaiCharan

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.indexOf` will return `-1` if the string does not include the substring, and the index of the substring otherwise. Therefor:

```
var substring = 'for',
  toSearch = 'iamgoingforawalk';
console.log(includesSubstring(toSearch, subString));

function includesSubstring(toSearch, subString) {
  return toSearch.indexOf(subString) !== -1;
}
```